# Como imprimir los registros de una tabla sql de manera horizontal y vertical

Tags: php, javascript, html, phpmyadmin

Estoy tratando de imprimir la siguiente tabla:

[image: Como deber ser la tabla]

Resulta que la logro imprimir y me queda de la siguiente manera

[image: Resultado de la impresión]

y el resultado de la consulta es este:

[image: Resultado de la consulta SQL]

y este es el codigo que estoy usando:

```html
<?php
  require_once'conexion.php';
 $materia = 15;
 $curso = 1;
 $codigo_profesor = 1;
 $sql= "SELECT a.codigo_alumno, a.nombre,    a.apellido, ac.titulo, cal.calificacion FROM calificaciones cal ".
  "INNER JOIN alumnos a ON a.codigo_alumno = cal.codigo_alumno ".
  "INNER JOIN cursos c ON c.codigo_curso = cal.codigo_curso ".
  "INNER JOIN actividades ac ON ac.codigo_actividad = cal.codigo_actividad ".
  "INNER JOIN materias m ON m.cdigo_materia = cal.codigo_materia ".
  "INNER JOIN profesores p ON p.codigo_profesor = cal.codigo_profesor ".
  "WHERE cal.codigo_materia = $materia AND cal.codigo_curso = $curso AND cal.codigo_profesor = $codigo_profesor ORDER BY a.codigo_alumno DESC";
 $consulta = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
 $asignacion = "";
 $asig = array();
 $x = 0;
 echo "<table border=1>";
   echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th>#</th>";
    echo "<th>Estudiante</th>";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consulta))
    {
     if($asignacion != $row['titulo']){
      echo "<th>".$row['titulo']."</th>";
      $asignacion =  $row['titulo'];
      $asig[$x] = $row['titulo'];  
      $x=$x+1;
     }
    }
   echo "</tr>";
   $i=1;
  $sql= "SELECT a.codigo_alumno, a.nombre, a.apellido, ac.titulo, cal.calificacion FROM calificaciones cal ".
  "INNER JOIN alumnos a ON a.codigo_alumno = cal.codigo_alumno ".
  "INNER JOIN cursos c ON c.codigo_curso = cal.codigo_curso ".
  "INNER JOIN actividades ac ON ac.codigo_actividad = cal.codigo_actividad ".
  "INNER JOIN materias m ON m.cdigo_materia = cal.codigo_materia ".
  "INNER JOIN profesores p ON p.codigo_profesor = cal.codigo_profesor ".
  "WHERE cal.codigo_materia = $materia AND cal.codigo_curso = $curso AND cal.codigo_profesor = $codigo_profesor ORDER BY a.codigo_alumno DESC";
  $consulta = mysqli_query($db, $sql); 
  $nombre="";
  $actividad="";
  while($datos = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consulta))
  {
   $actividad = $datos['titulo'];
   if($nombre != $datos['nombre']." ".$datos['apellido']){
    $sw = 0;
    echo "<tr>";   
    echo "<td>".$i."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$datos['nombre']." ".$datos['apellido']."</td>";
    $nombre = $datos['nombre']." ".$datos['apellido'];
   } else {
    $sw=1;
   }
   if($actividad == $datos['titulo']){
    echo "<td>".$datos['calificacion']."</td>"; 
   } 
   if($sw == 1){ 
    echo "</tr>";
   }
   $i = $i+1;
  }
  echo"</table>";
?>
```

Agradeceria mucho la ayuda que me puedan dar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Un modo de hacerlo es ordenar los datos que traes de la consulta en un único array que recorrer para crear la tabla.

Para ello en el ejemplo `$a_datos` sería el resultado de la consulta (sólo es necesario realizarla una vez), y sobre ese resultado determinamos por un lado cuantos títulos diferentes hay y por otro cuantos alumnos y que calificación tienen en los cursos.

```
$a_datos = array(
    array("codigo_alumno"=>30, "nombre"=>"Cristopher","apellidos" =>"Guerrero","titulo"=>"Taller la suma","calificacion"=>5),
    array("codigo_alumno"=>30, "nombre"=>"Cristopher","apellidos" =>"Guerrero","titulo"=>"Prueba","calificacion"=>4),
    array("codigo_alumno"=>30, "nombre"=>"Cristopher","apellidos" =>"Guerrero","titulo"=>"La suma","calificacion"=>4),
    array("codigo_alumno"=>1, "nombre"=>"Carlos","apellidos" =>"Maestre","titulo"=>"Prueba","calificacion"=>3)
);

$add_cols = 0; $a_titulos = array(); 
$codalum = 0; $a_alumn = array(); $row = 0;
foreach($a_datos as $datos) {
    if (!in_array($datos["titulo"],$a_titulos)) { array_push($a_titulos,$datos["titulo"]); }
}
foreach($a_datos as $datos) {
     if ($codalum!=$datos["codigo_alumno"]) {
        $row++;
         $a_alumn[$row]["order"] = $row;
         $a_alumn[$row]["nombre"] = $datos["nombre"]." ".$datos["apellidos"];         
         $codalum=$datos["codigo_alumno"];         
     }
    $th_prueba = array_search ($datos["titulo"], $a_titulos);
    $a_alumn[$row]["calificacion"][$th_prueba] = $datos["calificacion"];
 }
//print_r($a_titulos);
//print_r($a_alumn);
echo "<table border=1>";
 echo "<tr>";
  echo "<th>#</th>";
  echo "<th>Estudiante</th>";
foreach($a_titulos as $titulo) {
  echo "<th>".$titulo."</th>";
    $add_cols++;
}
 echo "</tr>";
 $codalum = 0;
 foreach($a_alumn as $alumdatos) {
    echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>".$alumdatos["order"]."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$alumdatos["nombre"]."</td>";
     foreach($a_titulos as $i=>$titulo) {
         echo "<td>".$alumdatos["calificacion"][$i]."</td>";         
     }
    echo "</tr>"; 
 }
echo "</table>";
```

Resultado:

```
#   Estudiante          Taller la suma  Prueba  La suma
1   Cristopher Guerrero 5               4       4
2   Carlos Maestre                      3
```

**EDICIÓN**
Para evitar avisos de `undeffined offset` se puede preguntar previamente al `echo` si el elemento existe.

Se cambiaría:

```
echo "<td>".$alumdatos["calificacion"][$i]."</td>";
```

por:

```
echo "<td>";
         if (isset($alumdatos["calificacion"][$i]) && $alumdatos["calificacion"][$i]>0) {
             echo $alumdatos["calificacion"][$i];     }   
         echo "</td>";
```

Comment: Gracias @Carmen por tu respuesta, lo hice tal cual pero me esta generado un par de warning, como si no existieran mas valores, que podrá ser???

Comment: @sebastianvalencia Los notice son por los elementos que no existen cuando se hace el echo "<td>".$alumdatos["calificacion"][$i]."</td>". Edito la respuesta para evitar los notice.

Comment: muchas gracias por tu ayuda, me funciono a la perfeccion.